# Get the scrollviews current contentOffset

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

How is the current offset for a Scrollview accessed?

I know the following

> [someScrollView contentOffset]

but does this return the current offset and if so how can this be casted to an integer?

I want to use this integer/image size to get the current image being viewed. OR is there better way to get the current image being displayed in the scrollview.

By the tag somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UIScrollView can scroll in both the horizontal and vertical directions. `contentOffset` returns a CGPoint struct that has x and y fields (which are both floats) to give you the offset in both dimensions.

To figure out which image is being viewed, you'd have to cross-reference the offset in the appropriate dimension(s) with the position of each image within the scroll view's content. The tag has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I just solved it, you were too fast with an answer. I would have deleted this. ;)

Comment: well, he answered your question, so you should accept it at least so that others know it is the right answer